# Repository for ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

I have created the following two repositories in the `DataAccessLayer` for the application which I am working on now.

1. `RoleRepository`
2. `TaskRepository`

`RoleRepository` is dealing with all the `Role` related operations like Adding `Role` in the Database and retrieving collection of Roles from the DataBase. `TaskRepository` does `Task` related operations as `RoleRepository`.

I want to Map `Role` with `Task`. I mean a Role is responsible for certain Tasks. This relationship is M:M. So I have created a table to store `RoleId` and `TaskId`. I want to display the Roles and corresponding Tasks in a GridView. So I need to save the `RoleId`,`TaskId` in the table and also need to retrieve Collection of RoleTaskViewModel.

- In which repository these operations need to be included?
- Do I need to create a new Repository?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're more interested in seeing the tasks associated to a role than the roles associated to a task. In that case, I would query it from the RoleRepository.

Answer (score 0):

I Think this should be a valueOjbect, if you are using Domain driven design pattern, there should be entity base class and all entity object should extend this base class.

Yes you should create a Value Object like :- RolesTasks in which you have collection object for both roles,tasks and you must use RoleRepository and TaskRepository.

Never need to created separate Repository "Repository should be created for EntityObject, not for ValueObject"